# Where can I find a hunting cabin?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm trying to complete "The Hunting Society" mission. The goal is to "visit one of the hunting cabins in the Frontier", but I can't find any. There don't seem to be any marked on the map.

Where are these cabins?

Answer (score 5):

There's one in Troy's Wood, in the North East corner, about on the border of Concord and Scotch Plains.

Answer (score 0):

In the northwest corner of frontier there is a fort. If you follow the mainroad out of that torwards the east there is a path that breaks off to the left (northeast) along that road is a cabin with a porchlight on and random people on the front porch. There is also a set of antlers on the porch. This is the only one I've found that is consistantly a mission pickup spot.

Comment: you should edit your answers just one answer that will contain the information in both of them, and delete the answer with the redundant information.

Answer (score -3):

I found one in concord for the feline feet mission but I can't find him now. That's the only one I know of so far